# Show tcp http request port 80 Linux

Tags: linux, http, httprequest, tcpdump

I using this command `sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'` but it show me every request several times. I also want to get from this command: time, referer and IP and show all of this in one line every request
in this format: [21:51:22] www.Google.co.il/mail IP 1.1.1.1

Comment: as an alternative, you can also use wireshark. Nice UI with all the features of `tcpdump`

Comment: Yes but i want to watch it from putty it will be possible?

Comment: Try [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug. I can't think of a reason as to why it would print the same request more than once. I'm experiencing this too except the first packet is using absolute sequence numbers and the second is using relative.

Answer (score 2):

you can just run the following command for showing you `tcp traffic to/from port 80`

```
tcpdump 'tcp port 80' -i eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ngrep will show everything on one line including time, referrer, and host.

```
ngrep -d eth1 -q "GET " -W single 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'


T 2014/03/23 22:57:45.959936 192.168.1.71:56718 -> 67.67.5.144:80 [AP] GET /clients/wfie/staticMaps/113.gif HTTP/1.1..Host: weather.wdtinc.com..Connection: keep-alive..Cache-Control: max-age=0..Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8..If-None-Match: W/"1f0683-19ef-4f54de24fa540"..If-Modified-Since: Sun, 23 Mar 2014 22:46:05 GMT..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36..Referer: http://www.14news.com/..Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch..Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8....
```

Also, if you just want to filter on tcp port 80 than you can use:

```
'tcp port 80 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'
```

and if you only want **outgoing** requests on port 80 add direction:

```
'tcp dst port 80 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'
```